# How to store elements from my regression in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regression

My problem is that I am trying to regress many individual columns against one set column. I've created a for loop that is successful at doing this, however I need a method that's able to record the important results of the regression before the data is overwritten by the next regression in the loop. Right now I have

```
    WTI_results=[]
    for i in range(13):
        OLSWTI= sm.OLS(df_opec.iloc[0:39,i],df_opec['WTI_price']).fit()
        d={[df_opec.columns[i]],[OLSWTI.params], [OLSWTI.rsquared],[OLSWTI.pvalues]}
    WTI_results=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    WTI_results.columns= ['Country', 'Beta', 'R-Squared', 'P-Value']
    print(WTI_results)
```

This returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' right now, but I'm not even sure if this is an appropriate way to be going about it. D is probably just overwriting itself as well but I'm not sure. Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: do you have any example data? The biggest problem here is that you're trying to create `d` as a dictionary, but you're just passing in individual values rather than key:value pairs, which is required for dictionary creation

Comment: The beginning data is an existing dataframe. It has 40 rows and 14 columns. I am pulling one column via iloc and regressing it against one constant column. I'm then trying to pull attributes from the variable the regression results are stored in and save them into a new dataframe. I'm not sure how to give example data for it.